# Settings buttons from a script in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an RTS on UnityEngine. Like the age of empire series there is a menu at the bottom of screen that depends of the object that you select.
Therefore, I created a class SObject (for selectable object) from which all objects inherit. For example, there is a class SHarvester, a class SAnimals, etc... The class SObject has an attribute :

```
[SerializeField]
private List<UnityAction> m_buttonCreation = new List<UnityAction>();
```

This list contains the methods specific to the object which will be linked to the buttons of the menu at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Buttons which will be linked to a method defined by the List above]

Everything is working well if you defined the list from the script.

But I would like to have prefabs of unit or building in the editor and to define the list of method directly from the inspector. But the unityAction types doesn't displayed in inspector.

**Is there a way of displaying the UnityAction type in inspector ?** Something like the button component :[image: UnityAction serialized field in button component]

I apologize if I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sticking to a `UnityAction` you could just use:

```cs
[SerializeField]
List<UnityEvent> m_buttonCreation = new List<UnityEvent>();
```

Which will show up like this in your inspector
[image]

The default UnityButton component has `UnityEvent`s and not `UnityAction`s anyway:

`Button.cs`

```cs
namespace UnityEngine.UI
{
    [AddComponentMenu("UI/Button", 30)]
    public class Button : Selectable, IPointerClickHandler, IEventSystemHandler, ISubmitHandler
    {
        protected Button();

        public ButtonClickedEvent onClick { get; set; }

        public virtual void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData);
        public virtual void OnSubmit(BaseEventData eventData);

        public class ButtonClickedEvent : UnityEvent
        {
            public ButtonClickedEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

and ofcourse the `UnityEvent` works with a `UnityAction` so IMHO you should just change Action to Event.

`UnityEvent.cs`

```cs
public class UnityEvent : UnityEventBase
{

    [RequiredByNativeCode]
    public UnityEvent();

    // This is what runs when you click on the (+) sign
    public void AddListener(UnityAction call);
    public void Invoke();
    // This is what runs when you click on the (-) sign
    public void RemoveListener(UnityAction call);
    protected override MethodInfo FindMethod_Impl(string name, object targetObj);
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but then I linked the button and the onClick action with the function AddListener(UnityAction method). The argument has to be a UnityAction and not a UnityEvent. Is there another way to connect a unityEvent and the OnClick action of a button ?

Comment: I dont really understand you. You can just drag and drop functions to this list. Thats what you want or not?

Comment: Okey i rearead it and i think i know what you want to achieve.
You want to basically add actions to this list. Than bind these actions to buttons right?

Comment: More specifically, in my game, if a user click on an object, a function in UIManager will be called to bind the actions of the buttons with the list of the attribute that I describe above. This actions could be for example : attack or defence if the object is a unit,  create a warrior or improve skills of harvesters if the object is a building.